# ButtonRenderer uses different background colors than Button in 16-bits

Tags: .net, winforms, button, colors

In a custom control, deriving from Button, the ButtonRenderer.DrawButton() draws a button, in various states.

All is fine when the display settings in Windows are set to a color-depth of 32-bits, but once, it is set to 16-bits, the color does not match one of a regular WinForms button and it stands out in my UI, which I do not really want.

I've replicated this using a minimal example code like this.

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 250, 120);
        ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(e.Graphics, rect, PushButtonState.Normal);

        rect = new Rectangle(300, 300, 250, 120);
        ControlPaint.DrawButton(e.Graphics, rect, ButtonState.Normal);
    }
```

which gives this...

[image: Rendered Buttons]

I'm sure you will all notice that the two "buttons" drawn by the DrawButton methods have a slightly lighter color than the standard button, and Form background (which I didn't change and left as the default which is "Control")...
If you zoom enough, you can see that it is alternating pixels of the correct background color and another brighter color...

I spotted this issue because our users are using Remote Desktop (RDP) to connect to our applications. Forcing the remote desktop settings to 32-bits resolves the problem but I think it has a performance impact, and some of our users are working overseas over relatively slow broadband links... so enforcing 32-bits is an option I would prefer to avoid.
It also happens in front of a PC, by setting the display settings to 16-bits colors.

Do you please have any ideas? Is it some kind of bug with ButtonRenderer and ControlPaint classes, or is there a way around this? (I'm using .Net 4.0).

Comment: Just to simplify - ButtonRenderer.DrawButton calls ControlPaint.DrawButton internally making them equivalent calls.

Comment: @JohnArlen - If the user has enabled a windows theme (like XP's Luna, etc) the ButtonRenderer call draws taking account of the Windows theme while the ControlPaint call draws without taking account of the theme (ie. looks like classic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ControlPaint.DrawButton is a wrapper around Win32's [DrawFrameControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It renders to a bitmap, then draws the bitmap to your Graphics display context.  The color dithering/approximation is happening at that bitmap layer.  I ran out of time to experiment further but...

If you merely call DrawFrameControl yourself, all works:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
public static extern bool DrawFrameControl(IntPtr hDC, ref RECT rect, int type, int state);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;

    public RECT(Rectangle r)
    {
        this.left = r.Left;
        this.top = r.Top;
        this.right = r.Right;
        this.bottom = r.Bottom;
    }
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (Application.RenderWithVisualStyles)
         ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(.....)
    else
    {
         var rect = new RECT(new Rectangle(10, 110, 100, 100));
         DrawFrameControl(e.Graphics.GetHdc(), ref rect, 4, 0x10 | (int)ButtonState.Normal);
    }

    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

EDIT: Added optional call to themes

Comment: Thank you. This works indeed, although it doesn't support themes like ButtonRenderer does. The fact that the color get dithered even if it can be displayed correctly in the first place seems like a bug in the framework to me?

Comment: Add a check for Theming and do it one way or the other... Edited OnPaint above with a sample.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good workaround, although even when the button is themed, ButtonRenderer.DrawButton the button is dithered and does not look like a normal themed control... Do you also think it is a bug in the .Net library in question, if so, I could try to report it?